# How to use a react-router Link or history.push within a gridjs cell

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gridjs

I am using react router and gridjs and want to display a link within a cell that the user can click to get to a detail page.

As a first approach I tried using a column formatter:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Grid } from 'gridjs-react';

const linkFormatter = (cell, row) =>
  _(
    <Link to={`/jobs/${row.cells[1].data}`} className="font-bold">
      {cell}
    </Link>
  );

...

<Grid
  data={[
    ['Job A', '123'],
    ['Job B', '124']
  ]}
  columns={{
    {name: 'Name', formatter: linkFormatter},
    'Job Id'}}
/>
```

I get the following error:
`Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

Here is another approach I tried using `useHistory`:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const CellLink = ({ item }) => {
  let history = useHistory();
  function handleClick() {
    history.push(`/jobs/${item.jobId}`);
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} className="font-bold">
      View
    </button>
  );
};

...

<Grid
  data={data.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    button: _(<CellLink item={item} />),
  }))}
  columns={columns}
/>
```

If i use CellLink outside Grid in the same component it works, but if I use it within a cell, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

Is there a way to make `<Link />` or `history` from react-router work inside a cell gridjs? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any <Router /> component in any parent component?

Answer (score 0):

**Send the history as a prop to CellLink**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const CellLink = ({ item, history }) => {
  function handleClick() {
    history.push(`/jobs/${item.jobId}`);
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} className="font-bold">
      View
    </button>
  );
};

...

const WrapperComponent = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
    <Grid
      data={data.map((item) => ({
        ...item,
        button: _(<CellLink item={item} history={history} />),
      }))}
      columns={columns}
    />
  )
}
```